# Recursive function to calculate successor of a numeric string

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I want to write a recursive function which calculates `Succ(‘2468’) = '2469'`. `‘2468’` is a numeric string.

The exercice give me some predefined function such as `last(ch)`, which returns the last caracter of a string, `start(ch)`, returns `ch` without the last caracter, `addEnd(ch, c)`, adds `c` at the end of `ch` and ask me to return a string as final result (i.e., `suc("123")="124"`)

I tried this code but it works only for a string with 2 characters. If the length of my string is > 2, it doesn't work:

```
int successor (char*ch)
{
 if (strlen (ch)==1)
 return (int(*ch))+1);
 else 
  return ((int(*ch))*10+successor(ch+1));}
```

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. The snippet you posted won't compile even if pasted into a proper C framework.

Comment: The code you show won't work even for two characters, as it can't be built. Is it supposed to be pseudo-code? Then you need to say that, and still make it *complete* (like what are you comparing `length(ch)` against?).

Comment: As for the logic, the algorithm itself: Start with a pen and a piece of paper. Work it all out there first. And remember the limitations you have (like an `int` being a signed 32-bit value, which therefore could hold only four bytes or "characters").

Comment: Even after your modifications, the code is not valid C. It is, on the other hand, valid C++.

Comment: @WeatherVane why would you expect code that can compile? What if the OP is having trouble getting even to that stage?

Comment: @גלעדברקן because OP said "it works only for a string with 2 characters", so we know OP's code compiles. However, the code he posted here does not.

Comment: @WeatherVane ah, makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no need for multiplication or use of powers. Given the extra predefined functions you indicated were provided, I think the intention here was for a recursive way to express long addition with carry. I don't know C but here's an illustration in JavaScript that has very close syntax. I hope this helps.

```js
function successor(s){
  if (s.length == 1){
    if (s == '9'){
      return '10';
      
    } else {
      // Return the successor character,
      // not sure how this looks in C.
      return String.fromCharCode(
        s.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
    }
  }
  
  let rightmost = successor(last(s));
  
  // No carry so just return
  // the string with the last
  // character incremented
  if (rightmost != '10'){
    return addEnd(start(s), rightmost);
    
  // We have a carry so
  // continue the recursion
  } else {
    return addEnd(successor(start(s)), '0');
  }
}

function last(s){
  return s.substr(-1);
}
function start(s){
  return s.substr(0, s.length - 1);
}
function addEnd(s, c){
  return s + c;
}
    
console.log(successor('2999'));
```

Answer (score 2):

A key problem is this logic:

```
(int(*ch))*10+successor(ch+1)
```

the multiplication by 10 is insufficient for larger numbers.  We need to multiply by a power of 10 and we already calculated that power but didn't hang onto it:

```
strlen (ch)
```

or more specifically:

```
strlen(ch) - 1
```

A complete solution:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define digit(c) (c - '0')

int successor(char *string)
{
    size_t power = strlen(string) - 1;

    if (power == 0)
    {
        return digit(*string) + 1;
    }

    return digit(*string) * pow(10, power) + successor(string + 1);
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", successor("2999"));

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> ./a.out
3000
>
```

**TODO**

What happens if `successor()` is passed an empty string:

```
printf("%d\n", successor(""));
```

How can you modify the code to fix this?  First decide what the function *should* return in this situation.  What happens if `successor()` is passed a string that represents a number too large to be contained in an `int`:

```
printf("%d\n", successor("8589934592"));
```

How can you modify the code to fix this?  Again, first decide what the function *should* return in this situation.

Comment: thank you @cdlane for your answer, very useful. if the string is empty, i think returning "0". else, the exercice give me some predefined function such as last(ch) which returns the last caracter of a string/ start(ch), returns ch without the last caracter, addEnd(ch, c), adds c at the end of ch and ask me to return a string as final result (i.e (suc("123")="124")

Comment: Given the OPs extra predefined functions, I don't think this or the use of power was the intention in the exercise.

Comment: Also, this is not returning a string, as the OP indicated it should in a comment under this answer (their own code sample notwithstanding).

Comment: @גלעדברקן, I understand but, as described, functions like `start(ch)` and `addEnd(ch, c)`, as well as returning a string, get into memory allocation issues,  which in **C** are *nothing* like JavaScript nor Python, so I wouldn't proceed without a more precise specification.

Comment: OP said the extra functions were "predefined." What do you mean by "I wouldn't proceed" - do you mean you wouldn't try to offer help to the OP?

Comment: @גלעדברקן, without seeing the actual predefined code, I could do as much harm as good.  I don't know where the strings are being allocated nor freed, so I'd have to make potentially incorrect assumptions, possibly leading to segment faults.  Again, JavaScript, Python or meta-code, no problem.  But not in **C**.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for explaining.